# How to listen to Test Suite changes in order to change some configurations

Tags: java, junit, junit4, test-suite, spring-test

I have many Spring Test classes (defined using `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner)`) that I want to group in test suites so that I load new configurations once for every suite instead of for every test class.

Right now I have a `TestExecutionListener` listener to every Spring test  that will reload the configurations, but I want to save that since many tests share the same configurations.

Sadly, niether Spring supports listening to `JUnit TestSuite`s nor `JUnit` supports the listener concept for `TestSuite`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to perform actions before/after a junit test suite, you can use [@BeforeClass](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) and [@AfterClass](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/AfterClass.html), or even [@ClassRule](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/ClassRule.html). You can do your setup in there for the entire suite. Using the following example:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ ExpectedFailureTest.class, RetryTest.class })
public class BeforeClassSuite {
  @BeforeClass
  public static void beforeClass() {
    System.out.println("beforeClass");
  }

  @AfterClass
  public static void afterClass() {
    System.out.println("afterClass");
  }

  @ClassRule
  public static ExternalResource resource = new ExternalResource() {
    @Override
    protected void before() throws Throwable {
      System.out.println("before");
    };

    @Override
    protected void after() {
      System.out.println("after");
    };
  };
}
```

This produces as output:

```
before
beforeClass
... output from tests
afterClass
after
```